# Timeouts with singleton instance of DefaultHttpClient

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm using a *singleton* instance of `DefaultHttpClient` in conjunction with `PoolingClientConnectionManager` to perform a cconsiderable number (multiple per second) of HTTP operations in a multithreaded fashion. My code is basically:

```
final HttpParams httpClientParams = new BasicHttpParams();
httpClientParams.setParameter("http.protocol.version", HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpClientParams, 700);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpClientParams, 700);
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(poolingClientConnectionManager, httpClientParams);
```

I will then access the `client` object from multiple threads in parallel.

My problem is, that the timeouts do not get respected and I have HTTP requests that take much longer than the 700ms specified.

- Is it safe to set the timeout on the client as I do above?
- Is it safe to use a singleton instance of `DefaultHttpClient` for *many* parallel requests?

Comment: It seems the `PoolingClientConnectionManager`'s pool was too small, therefore the requests took a long time. Enlarging the pool has solved the issue as it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Is it safe to set the timeout on the client as I do above?

Yes, it is safe. However, HttpClient level parameters represent the *default* settings inherited by all requests. One should not meddle with those settings at runtime. It is generally better to use request level parameters to configure individual requests.

- Is it safe to use a singleton instance of DefaultHttpClient for many parallel requests?

Not only safe but also strongly advisable. By sharing the same HttpClient instance individual requests can be executed more efficiently by re-using a shared pool of persistent connections.

Please also make sure your expectations with regards to timeout behavior are correct. Timeout values represent the maximum period of inactivity between two *consecutive* i/o operations, not the maximum total request execution time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, provided some insight! If you had a link to the docs where all this is stated it would be even better.

Comment: @Fred anything particularly wrong with the HttpClient tutorial? http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html